# Select2 - Prevent clearing of template on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a [Select2](https://github.com/select2/select2) field with the multiple setting enabled and a custom HTML selection template that includes an input field.

However, it seems that whenever a new option is added or deleted, the text entered in the custom input field is lost - looks like Select2 reinitializes/resets the template on the change event.

Is there a way to keep the text entered on all option items even after selecting/removing items?

```js
var stopOpening = false;

$('#my-select').select2({
  width: '100%',
  multiple: true,
  templateSelection: function(item) {
    var $result = $('<span  class="label">' + item.text + '</span><input class="input" placeholder="Input Text Here" onclick="clickMe()">');
    return $result;
  }
}).on({
  "select2:unselecting": function(e) {
    if (e.params.args.originalEvent.target.className === 'input') {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  },
  "select2:opening": function(e) {
    if (stopOpening == true) {
      stopOpening = false;
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});

clickMe = function() {
  stopOpening = true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="my-select">
  <option>red</option>
  <option>blue</option>
  <option>green</option>
  <option>yellow</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option>black</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

your result to be returned must be like this

```
var $result = $('<span  class="label">' + item.text + '</span>');
```

not like this

```
$result = $('<span  class="label">' + item.text + '</span><input class="input" placeholder="Input Text Here" onclick="clickMe()">');
```